RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded with pickle package with Python pickle
Background:
I was using tweepy to retrieve tweets and their metadata. I was using a simple Python list to append all Response and trying to serialize it with python pickle.
Problem:

I encounted this RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during pickle.dump().
I increased the recursion limit via sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) but got the same problem.
I tried to use pickle.dumps(responses) to convert it to byte-object and save to disk. It works. However, when I tried to load it via pickle.load() or pickle.loads(), they both failed and prompted the same 'Recursion Error'.

Code snippet:
def retrieve_tweets(tweet_ids):
    tweet_fields=['id', 'text', 'author_id', 'created_at', 'conversation_id']
    responses = client_bearer.get_tweets(ids=tweet_ids,tweet_fields=tweet_fields)
    return responses

# retrieve tweets in batch
batch_size=100
responses=[]
ids=list(sample['tweetId'])
for index,i in tqdm(enumerate(range(0, len(ids),batch_size))):
    batch_ids=ids[i:i+batch_size]
    if index!=0 and index%15==0:
        print(f"To avoid rate limits, sleeping for 16 minutes...")
        time.sleep(60*16)
        print(f"Resuming...")
    try:
        responses.append(retrieve_tweets(batch_ids))
    except Exception as error:
        print(i)
        print(error)
        for each in responses.data:
            results.append(each.data)

# save binary raw results to file
responses_bin=pickle.dumps(responses)
with open('helpful_src_raw.bin','wb') as f:
    f.write(responses_bin)

# read from binary data
with open('helpful_src_raw.bin','rb') as f:
    data_bin=f.read()
data=pickle.loads(data_bin) ### THIS IS WHERE IT TRIGGERED THE ERROR

Version:
I was using python==3.10 with tweepy==4.14.
Much appreciated if anyone can help with this.

Most of the code here is irrelevant to the problem, and it can't be run because of all the missing parts. If the error is in pickling and unpickling the data, you need to provide a [mre] that would consist of harcoded, minimal sample data, and the code that pickles and unpickles it, plus the complete error traceback that running this exact code causes.

@ThierryLathuille Many thanks for your comments. I understand it's better to provide a minimal example but it's a bit difficult to show Tweepy output here but I will try to update this later.
